# How to use bold text in QGIS font marker symbol?

Tags: qgis, markers, font, symbology

Is it possible to use bold text with the Font marker symbol in a QGIS (point) layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not currently possible (as of version 2.4). It's a valid request though - you should file it over at http://hub.qgis.org/issues